# FINDSTR in CMD - whole words only

Tags: cmd, findstr

I use Windows 7 and often use the FINDSTR command to search in * .log files.

I would like to ask if it is possible to search for whole words only.

Because often when I type:

```
findstr "su" *.log
```

I get:

```
su
super
unsubscribe
```

etc.

Comment: Type `findstr /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the help message very carefully…

Comment: I have voted to close this question, as it is of no use to future readers. You question could have easily been solved by reading the usage information for the specific command you were using. You have therefore made no reasonable attempt at investigating how to perform the task before posting your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 options, depending on the requirements. Consider you want all lines where `su` is a standalone word in a string:

```
user can su
su
super
unsubscribe
```

then run use word boundary with `regex`:

```
findstr /rc:"\<su\>" *.log
```

which will match both:

```
user can su
su
```

if however you only want the standalone word in a string `su`, then use e`x`act match:

```
findstr /x "su" *.log
```

add `/i` if your word needs to be matched in upper, lower or mixed case.